# angularjs $compile not working for custom template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

im trying to render a custom template using the $compile but i keep getting

```
unrecognized expression: {{senddata}}
```

My code is like below

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, ngDialog,$http,$compile){
      $scope.afterasset = function (selectedValues) {
           $scope.senddata = 'testdata';
           var data = $compile( '{{senddata}}' )( $scope );
      }
}
```

Any idea guys ? thanks :)

Comment: usage is correct. can you provide a plnkr

Answer (score 1):

Its does't work because $compile provider need a **HTML string with element tags** or **wraped jQlite** element.

Try -

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, ngDialog,$http,$compile){
      $scope.afterasset = function (selectedValues) {
           $scope.senddata = 'testdata';
           var data = $compile( '<p>{{senddata}}</p>' )( $scope );
      }
}
```